# Problema ao pegar informações do usuário com o react-native-fbsdk

Tags: react-native, api

Tenho uma app móvel feita em react native, estou a fazer login via facebook usando a lib react-native-fbsdk mas funciona porem estou a ter problemas em resgatar os dados do utilizador, tive a ver alguns tópicos aqui no forum da mesma situação e segui como alguns deles mas mesmo assim não funciona. vou passar abaixo o código que estou a usar.

Função de login

```
loginFacebook = () => {
  LoginManager.logInWithPermissions(["public_profile", "email"]).then(
    function(result) {
      if (result.isCancelled) {
        console.log("Login cancelled");
      } else {
        AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().then(data => {
          const processRequest = new GraphRequest(
            "/me?fields=name,email,picture.type(large)",
            null,
            this.get_Response_Info
          );
          new GraphRequestManager().addRequest(processRequest).start();
        });
      }
    },
    function(error) {
      console.log("Login fail with error: " + error);
    }
  );
};
```

Função que devia pegar os dados

```
get_Response_Info = (error, result) => {
  if (error) {
    Alert.alert("Error fetching data: " + error.toString());
  } else {
    console.log(result.toString());
  }
};
```

Nesta função o `console.log(result)` não executa acho pois no console não bem nada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu utilizei o react-native-fbsdk a algum tempo atrás, e eu fiz da seguinte forma, eu criei um arquivo em separado com toda a lógica de login.

```js
import {
  LoginManager, AccessToken, GraphRequest, GraphRequestManager,
} from 'react-native-fbsdk';

import { AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';

const getAccountInfo = accessData => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  new GraphRequestManager()
    .addRequest(
      new GraphRequest(
        '/me',
        {
          accessToken: accessData.accessToken,
          parameters: {
            fields: {
              string: 'id, name, email, picture.type(large)',
            },
          },
        },
        (error, result) => {
          if (error) {
            return reject(error);
          }

          return resolve(result);
        },
      ),
    )
    .start();
});

export const facebookLogin = async () => {
  let result;
  let accessData;
  try {
    const offlineUser = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@Facebook:accessData');

    if (offlineUser) {
      accessData = JSON.parse(await AsyncStorage.getItem('@Facebook:accessData'));
    } else {
      result = await LoginManager.logInWithPermissions(['public_profile', 'email']);

      if (result.isCancelled) {
        return { error: 'Usuário cancelou o Login!' };
      }
      accessData = await AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
      await AsyncStorage.setItem('@Facebook:accessData', JSON.stringify(accessData));
    }
    const info = await getAccountInfo(accessData);
    return { user: info };
  } catch (err) {
    await AsyncStorage.removeItem('@Facebook:accessData');
    // return err.userInfo[Object.keys(err.userInfo)[2]].body;
    return { error: 'Houve um erro ao recuperar os dados!' };
  }
};
```

Na tela onde eu tenho o botão de login do Facebook, eu importei este arquivo e criei uma função para vincular ao botão:

```js
import { facebookLogin } from "../../services/facebook";

login_facebook = async () => {
    this.setState({ loading_facebook: true, loading: false });
    const response = await facebookLogin();
    if (response.error) {
      //Se o tipo do erro foi token expirado, chamar de novo a rotina para gerar um token novo

      this.setState({ error: response.error, loading: false });
      return false;
    }

    this.setState({
      user: response.user,
      loading: false,
      error: "",
      social_id: response.user.id,
      email: response.user.email,
      username: response.user.name,
      social_origem: "FACEBOOK"
    });
    this.autenticar_social();
  };
```

Eu tomei como base este projeto

https://github.com/Rocketseat/academy-facebook-auth

Aqui tem um tutorial explicando a instalação:

https://medium.com/reactbrasil/instalando-o-react-native-fbsdk-do-jeito-certo-9f0fada5be4

Comment: Valeu pela ajuda, graças a isso vou conseguir do jeito correcto e conseguir por a funcionar como queria e isso mesmo que indicou, obrigado

Comment: Só para complementar a pergunta para quem vier ajudar, eu fiz agora segui e implementei segundo o que mandas-te e sim esta perfeito a funcionar como queria, mais uma vez obrigado